# Can't install PHPUnit via PEAR, requires PEAR Installer >= 1.9.2, can't upgrade PEAR from 1.9.0

Tags: php, ubuntu, phpunit, pear

I read the other PHPUnit installation questions but haven't had any success. What is going on with my PEAR install?

```
$ sudo pear update-channels
Updating channel "components.ez.no"
Channel "components.ez.no" is up to date
Updating channel "doc.php.net"
Channel "doc.php.net" is up to date
Updating channel "pear.php.net"
Channel "pear.php.net" is up to date
Updating channel "pear.phpunit.de"
Channel "pear.phpunit.de" is up to date
Updating channel "pear.symfony-project.com"
Channel "pear.symfony-project.com" is up to date
Updating channel "pecl.php.net"
Channel "pecl.php.net" is up to date
$ sudo pear upgrade pear
Nothing to upgrade
$ sudo pear install phpunit/PHPUnit
phpunit/PHPUnit requires PEAR Installer (version >= 1.9.2), installed version is 1.9.0
phpunit/PHPUnit can optionally use PHP extension "dbus"
phpunit/DbUnit requires PEAR Installer (version >= 1.9.2), installed version is 1.9.0
phpunit/File_Iterator requires PEAR Installer (version >= 1.9.2), installed version is 1.9.0
phpunit/PHP_CodeCoverage requires PEAR Installer (version >= 1.9.1), installed version is 1.9.0
phpunit/PHP_CodeCoverage requires package "phpunit/File_Iterator" (version >= 1.2.2)
phpunit/PHP_CodeCoverage can optionally use PHP extension "xdebug" (version >= 2.0.5)
phpunit/PHPUnit_MockObject requires PEAR Installer (version >= 1.9.2), installed version is 1.9.0
phpunit/PHPUnit_Selenium requires PEAR Installer (version >= 1.9.2), installed version is 1.9.0
phpunit/PHP_TokenStream requires PEAR Installer (version >= 1.9.1), installed version is 1.9.0
No valid packages found
install failed
$ pear list
Installed packages, channel pear.php.net:
=========================================
Package          Version  State
Archive_Tar      1.3.7    stable
Cache_Lite       1.7.11   stable
Console_Getopt   1.3.1    stable
HTTP_Request2    2.0.0RC1 beta
Net_URL2         0.3.1    beta
PEAR             1.9.3    stable
Structures_Graph 1.0.4    stable
XML_RPC2         1.1.1    stable
XML_Util         1.2.1    stable
greg@ubuntu:~$ pear -V
PEAR Version: 1.9.0
PHP Version: 5.3.6
Zend Engine Version: 2.3.0
Running on: Linux ubuntu 2.6.32-32-generic-pae #62-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 20 22:10:33 UTC 2011 i686
```

`pear list` reports 1.9.3 installed, `pear -V` reports 1.9.0!?!

**Update** Tried KingCrunch suggestion.

```
$ sudo pear install -f pear
[sudo] password for greg: 
downloading PEAR-1.9.3.tgz ...
Starting to download PEAR-1.9.3.tgz (295,774 bytes)
...........................done: 295,774 bytes
install ok: channel://pear.php.net/PEAR-1.9.3
PEAR: Optional feature webinstaller available (PEAR's web-based installer)
PEAR: Optional feature gtkinstaller available (PEAR's PHP-GTK-based installer)
PEAR: Optional feature gtk2installer available (PEAR's PHP-GTK2-based installer)
PEAR: To install optional features use "pear install pear/PEAR#featurename"
$ pear -V
PEAR Version: 1.9.0
PHP Version: 5.3.6
Zend Engine Version: 2.3.0
Running on: Linux ubuntu 2.6.32-32-generic-pae #62-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 20 22:10:33 UTC 2011 i686
```

Comment: try `sudo pear install -f pear`

Comment: That didn't work unfortunately, see my update to the question.

Comment: (sudo) `pear upgrade pear` from your post was useful for me to bump my version, so thanks for asking this question!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You basically have 2 pear installations on your machine, and the "pear upgrade" command updates the other one, not itself.

I assume that the pear version you're running has been installed via ubuntu's apt.

Find out where it has been installed with `apt` (on Debian/Ubuntu):

```
$ dpkg -L php-pear
...
/usr/share/php/PEAR.php
...
/usr/bin/pear
```

Now let's see where pear installs the files to:

```
$ pear config-get php_dir
/usr/share/php
```

On my machine, it is the same - but probably not on yours, which is the problem. Fix it by setting the `php_dir`, as well as the `bin_dir`:

```
$ pear config-set php_dir /usr/share/php
$ pear config-set bin_dir /usr/bin
```

**Alternatively**, remove the ubuntu pear and install it freshly from http://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar

Comment: Thank you, you were correct. I installed PHP 5.3.6 from source so I could enable FPM support for nginx. `$ pear config-get php_dir
/etc/php/lib/php`

Comment: @cweiske, I have same problem (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8949963/phpunit-pear-upgrading-errors) but `pear config-get php_dir` and `dpkg -L php-pear` pointing same address.

Comment: How can i know where my pear is installed on Mac Os X? This doesn't work there:  dpkg -L php-pear

Comment: @Steve I added a question for that on http://stackoverflow.com/q/12538165/467453. I am not sure what hose php_dir and bin_dir paths should be set to on Mac OS X / MAMP.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not successful with the pear part have a look at this.

```
wget https://phar.phpunit.de/phpunit.phar
chmod +x phpunit.phar
mv phpunit.phar /usr/local/bin/phpunit
```

ref: http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/installation.html

You can also immediately use the PHAR after you have downloaded it;

```
wget https://phar.phpunit.de/phpunit.phar
php phpunit.phar
```