# Upgrading PEAR on Mac OS X / MAMP

Tags: php, macos, pear, mamp

I am installing PHPUnit on Mac OS X and I am having problems with my current PEAR version. Existing SO questions don't resolve the problem. The current PEAR version is listed as 1.9.1. PHPUnit requires 1.9.4.

```
[le programmeur]$which pear
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/bin/pear

[le programmeur]$pear -V
PEAR Version: 1.9.1
PHP Version: 5.3.5
Zend Engine Version: 2.3.0

[le programmeur]$pear config-get php_dir
/Users/rallen8440/pear/share/pear
```

After running `pear install -f pear` PEAR 1.9.4 is supposedly installed, and `running pear upgrade pear` "indicates" that we are at the latest version.

```
[le programmeur]$/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/bin/pear install -f pear
WARNING: "pear/Console_Getopt" is deprecated in favor of "pear/Console_GetoptPlus"
downloading PEAR-1.9.4.tgz ...
Starting to download PEAR-1.9.4.tgz (296,332 bytes)
.............................................................done: 296,332 bytes
install ok: channel://pear.php.net/PEAR-1.9.4
PEAR: Optional feature webinstaller available (PEAR's web-based installer)
PEAR: Optional feature gtkinstaller available (PEAR's PHP-GTK-based installer)
PEAR: Optional feature gtk2installer available (PEAR's PHP-GTK2-based installer)
PEAR: To install optional features use "pear install pear/PEAR#featurename"
[le programmeur]$/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/bin/pear -V
PEAR Version: 1.9.1
PHP Version: 5.3.5
Zend Engine Version: 2.3.0

[le programmeur]$pear upgrade pear
pear/pear is already installed and is the same as the released version 1.9.4
upgrade failed
```

However when pear install phpunit/PHPUnit is run, it says otherwise:

```
[le programmeur]$pear install phpunit/PHPUnit
Did not download optional dependencies: phpunit/PHP_Invoker, use --alldeps to download automatically
phpunit/PHPUnit requires PEAR Installer (version >= 1.9.4), installed version is 1.9.1
phpunit/PHPUnit can optionally use package "phpunit/PHP_Invoker" (version >= 1.1.0)
phpunit/File_Iterator requires PEAR Installer (version >= 1.9.2), installed version is 1.9.1
phpunit/Text_Template requires PEAR Installer (version >= 1.9.4), installed version is 1.9.1
phpunit/PHP_CodeCoverage requires PEAR Installer (version >= 1.9.4), installed version is 1.9.1
phpunit/PHP_CodeCoverage requires package "phpunit/File_Iterator" (version >= 1.3.0)
phpunit/PHP_CodeCoverage requires package "phpunit/Text_Template" (version >= 1.1.1)
phpunit/PHP_CodeCoverage can optionally use PHP extension "xdebug" (version >= 2.0.5)
phpunit/PHP_Timer requires PEAR Installer (version >= 1.9.2), installed version is 1.9.1
phpunit/PHPUnit_MockObject requires PEAR Installer (version >= 1.9.4), installed version is 1.9.1
phpunit/PHPUnit_MockObject requires package "phpunit/Text_Template" (version >= 1.1.1)
phpunit/PHP_TokenStream requires PEAR Installer (version >= 1.9.4), installed version is 1.9.1
No valid packages found
install failed

[le programmeur]$pear -V
PEAR Version: 1.9.1
PHP Version: 5.3.5
Zend Engine Version: 2.3.0
```

There used to be a PEAR installed in /usr/bin/pear but it's no longer there:

```
[le programmeur]$ls /usr/bin/pear
pear_old  peardev
```

The `~/.profile` PATH is pointing to `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/bin`:

```
# Mod path
export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/bin:$PATH
```

I have no clue as to what I am missing here. Halp!

Comment: I finally gave up trying it with PEAR and i downloaded PHPUnit files ans placed them inside app/vendor/.

Answer (score 0):

You have two pear installations on your machine, as described on https://stackoverflow.com/a/6596669/282601

The `pear` command you're executing is not updating itself but the second installation.

The only solution is to configure pear so that it upgrades itself, by changing the paths in `pear config-show` - or to throw all installations away and install from scratch.