# PEAR fails to install on Ubuntu 12.x

Tags: php, ubuntu, wrapper, pear, channel

I have a problem I thought would be solved with Ubuntu 12.10, but no luck... I had the same thing with 12.04 when trying to install something with PEAR :

```
Warning: file_exists(): Unable to find the wrapper "channel" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? in Package.php on line 1518
PHP Warning:  file_exists(): Unable to find the wrapper "channel" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? in /usr/share/php/PEAR/Downloader/Package.php on line 1518
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /usr/share/php/pearcmd.php:0
PHP   2. PEAR_Command_Common->run() /usr/share/php/pearcmd.php:305
PHP   3. PEAR_Command_Install->doInstall() /usr/share/php/PEAR/Command/Common.php:271
PHP   4. PEAR_Downloader->download() /usr/share/php/PEAR/Command/Install.php:661
PHP   5. PEAR_Downloader_Package->initialize() /usr/share/php/PEAR/Downloader.php:279
PHP   6. PEAR_Downloader_Package->_fromFile() /usr/share/php/PEAR/Downloader/Package.php:160
PHP   7. file_exists() /usr/share/php/PEAR/Downloader/Package.php:1518
```

For this example, I tried to install PHPUnit, but it is the same message with any package.

I googled a lot on this and tried many solutions :

- uninstall it with apt-get remove
- purge it with apt-get purge
- delete the remaining files manually
- installing then upgrading it

Does anybody have any idea on how to fix this ?

Thanx !

> ***EDIT :***
>
> Always the same, it's when you post your question that the answer pops up !
>
> Here is the link to the trick that did it : https://stackoverflow.com/a/6596669/2061163
>
> This problem occured because I had two versions of PEAR installed on my system, don't know why...