# Dreamhost - Latest version of PEAR

Tags: php, pear, dreamhost

I'm on SSH on my Dreamhost account.

I need to install the HTTP_Request2 PHP library via pear

```
pear install HTTP_Request2
```

gives the following error

```
pear/HTTP_Request2 requires PEAR Installer (version >= 1.9.2), installed version is 1.9.1
```

Here's the output of  `pear -V`

```
PEAR Version: 1.9.1
```

I tried forcing an upgrade on the Dreamhost server

`pear upgrade --force http://pear.php.net/get/PEAR-1.9.2` and even `pear install PEAR-1.9.4`

but this errors out to: `pear/PEAR is already installed and is the same as the released version 1.9.4
install failed`

Anyone experience similar issues?

Comment: Have you contacted them? Typically DH is very fast to resolve issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two versions of pear installed. The one you run, and the one you upgrade.

`which pear` will return a different path than `pear list-files pear|grep script`; that's your problem.

Either run the installed one (from list-files), or set the paths so that the `which pear`-version gets updated (`pear config-show` and `pear config-set`).

See [Can't install PHPUnit via PEAR, requires PEAR Installer >= 1.9.2, can't upgrade PEAR from 1.9.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6596316/cant-install-phpunit-via-pear-requires-pear-installer-1-9-2-cant-upgrade/6596669#6596669) for more info.

Comment: 'pear list-files pear|grep bin' that cmd returns an empty string. How do I check my the DH server for the different versions

Comment: replace bin with script.