# Why don't I see my installed PEAR package in pear list?

Tags: php, installation, package, pear, package-managers

I've installed PHP 5.6 on my El Capitan OSX with `brew install php56 --with-pear`. This installs PHP in `/usr/local/Cellar/php56/5.6.18`
with a symlink from `/usr/local/opt/php56` to there. Seems to work fine.

OK, I need to install the Cache_Lite package, so I do `pear install Cache_Lite`. PEAR goes through its installation steps without complaint:

```
downloading Cache_Lite-1.7.16.tgz ...
Starting to download Cache_Lite-1.7.16.tgz (33,236 bytes)
.........done: 33,236 bytes
install ok: channel://pear.php.net/Cache_Lite-1.7.16
```

But when I do `pear list` Cache_Lite is nowhere to be seen:

```
Installed packages, channel pear.php.net:
=========================================
Package          Version State
Archive_Tar      1.4.0   stable
Console_Getopt   1.4.1   stable
PEAR             1.10.1  stable
Structures_Graph 1.1.1   stable
XML_Util         1.3.0   stable
```

When I check the php56 folder in Finder, I see there is a Cache folder there with the Cache_Lite files. And when I add the folder to my PHP pages with `ini_set("include_path", '/usr/local/opt/php56/lib/php:' . ini_get("include_path") );` my PHP page in the browser stops complaining it can't find Cache_Lite.

PEAR, Why don't you list Cache_Lite when you've installed Cache_Lite? Am I misunderstanding `pear list`?

Comment: Probably the same problem as http://stackoverflow.com/a/6596669/282601

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't install PHPUnit via PEAR, requires PEAR Installer >= 1.9.2, can't upgrade PEAR from 1.9.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6596316/cant-install-phpunit-via-pear-requires-pear-installer-1-9-2-cant-upgrade)